# $user = $facebook->getUser() returning 0 everytime. Am using the latest SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-authentication

Am using below code to check whether the user is logged in or not to Facebook.

```
<?php

// Awesome FB APP 
// Name: MyAPP 

require_once 'facebook.php';// this line calls our facebook.php file that is the 
//core of PHP facebook API
// Create our Application instance.

$facebook = new Facebook(array(

  'appId' => '250941738370233',

  'secret' => 'xxx',

  'cookie' => true,

)); // all we are doing is creating an array for facebook to use with our 

$user = $facebook->getUser();
echo $user;
//app id and app secret in and setting the cookie to true
if($user){
try {
  $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

  error_log($e);
  $user=null;

} // this code is saying if the session to the app is created use 
}
//the $me as a selector for the information or die

?>
```

But the $user is responding 0 everytime. Am badly stuck at this point. Can someone help me out here.

Comment: **Don't post your application secret publicly**

Comment: Yeah, read the FB OAuth documentation for why this is particularly scary. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/. Once your app secret is known, they can get an access token that allows them to modify any of your app's settings.

Comment: **Thanks to the StackOverflow moderators or devs** who have deleted that revision (I flagged this question) ;)

Answer (score 3):

> Am using below code to check whether the user is logged in or not to Facebook.

I’m suspecting that’s your problem right there.

You can not check if *any* user visiting your app is logged into Facebook – you will only get information about a user, if they have *connected* to your app before. And since I see nothing like it in your code, I assume you did not trigger that in any way before.

So please, start reading docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/login/

Answer (score 0):

Getting a 0 is to be expected. You should, on getting that, be redirecting the user to a login url. If you do that, the user will get one of those App authorisation screens you have seen, after which they will be redirected to whatevef url you have specified.

Check out the links provided, but also take a peek at http://www.facebookanswers.co.uk/?p=229 as I provide some examples there.

The example in my link really needs updating but if you look you will see that it checks to see if getuser returns false, and if so jumps to a login page.